# how do I fix the margin

Tags: html, css

**this is the goal poster**

[image]

**the is my poster**

[image]

can you read my code and tell me what I did wrong/ if there was an easier way
The project is to make a Motivational Poster website.

> TODO: Create a motivational post website.
> Style it how ever you like.
> Look at the goal image for inspiration.
> But it must have the following features:
>
> 1. The main h1 text should be using the Regular Libre Baskerville Font from Google Fonts:
>    https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Baskerville
> 2. The text should be white and background black.
> 3. Add your own image into the images folder inside assets. It should have a 5px white border.
> 4. The text should be center aligned.
> 5. Create a div to contain the h1, p and image elements. Adjust the margins so that the image and text are centered on the page.
>    Hint: You horizontally center a div by giving it a width of 50% and a margin-left of 25%.
>    Hint: Set the image to have a width of 100% so it fills the div.
> 6. Read about the text-transform property on MDN docs to make the h1 uppercase with CSS.
>    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

```css
h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', cursive;
}

p {
    color: white
}

body {
    background: black;
}


#texts {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


#box1 {
    border: 5px solid;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}


div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            <!-- <img src="max-harlynking-UdCNVHNgHdI-unsplash.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="50%" /> -->
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" alt="" width="100%" height="50%" />

            <h1 id="texts">let's a go!!!</h1>
            <p id="texts">we did it</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the picture should be center when minimized (take up half the screen) it look good but when full its centered but at the bottom.

*I've only just stared learn so I only know the extreme basic of html and CSS**

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? I've added `text-align: center;` to `#texts` to center both text elements. I've added a parent `<div>` to `#box1` and added `display: flex; justify-content: center;` so basically I've used to Flexbox to center `#box1` horizontally. Seems like what you want.

```css
h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Libre Baskerville", cursive;
}

p {
    color: white;
}

body {
    background: black;
}

#texts {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

#box1 {
    border: 5px solid;
    color: white;
    width: 450px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="box1">
                <!-- <img src="max-harlynking-UdCNVHNgHdI-unsplash.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="50%" /> -->
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1 id="texts">let's a go!!!</h1>
        <p id="texts">we did it</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fond her code that are should look like

Comment: @OsamuMidoriya What? I don't understand, did my answer help you?

Comment: why did you add two div box?

Comment: @OsamuMidoriya To make it work as what you wanted, the explanation is in my answer as well.

Comment: your answer is different from hers

Comment: why didn't you put the <p> and <h1> inside the div

Comment: Who "hers" @OsamuMidoriya?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code. You can increase the width via change the width of id "#box1".

```css
body{
  background-color:#000000;
}
#box1{
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#texts{
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            <!-- <img src="max-harlynking-UdCNVHNgHdI-unsplash.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="50%" /> -->
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" alt="" width="100%" height="50%" />

            <h1 id="texts">let's a go!!!</h1>
            <p id="texts">we did it</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```